# More than 2 nvidia video cards in one computer?

Tags: nvidia

Ubuntu 14.04, 64bit. There's a lot of "dual" video cards setup mentioned, but would it be possible to run three Nvidia cards in one computer?

Comment: To what end? What are you trying to accomplish? Many of the dual-card setups are one on-CPU graphics solution (for efficiency) plus a separate discrete card for high performance which is only used some of the time. This model wouldn't make much sense with a third wheel.

Comment: Blender 3d texture baking, that's really GPU hungry!

Comment: References: http://askubuntu.com/questions/171222/3-monitors-nvidia-intel-graphics/196914#196914 http://askubuntu.com/questions/246673/3-monitors-and-2-video-cards-intel-and-ati http://askubuntu.com/questions/30412/3-monitors-with-2-video-cards-not-working

Comment: BTW: why not get a quad head? Saves you a lot of trouble probably. Let the card handle this.

Comment: it's not about having 2+ monitors attached, it's about total combined GPU power!